# Creating a Wordpress URL Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect

I'm having a little trouble setting up a Wordpress URL redirect.

I've designed an ECommerce website with WooCommerce and I'd like to add a search bar that allows me to search filter products in the shop. I've added the default Wordpress search function and that works fine, however it display all types of content (posts, pages, products, etc.) from across the site.

If I search currently, the URL is as follows:

```
devsite/?s=searchterm
```

However, what I need the URL to be in order to display the shop page is this:

```
devsite/?s=searchterm&post_type=product
```

I've managed to cobble together the following code and placed it in my functions.php file. It nearly works, however, when I press search with the search term the website throws up an error saying it's being redirected too many times.

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . ( "&post_type=product" ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Please could someone explain why the web page is throwing up the too many redirects error and what I could possibly do to rectify this issue. My PHP knowledge is growing but limited and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is_search() Will always return true.  You can't use that to test against, since you're forwarding to a page that will also return true for is_search().  You're creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your IF condition, you are checking if the URL contain a get parameter and that get parameter `$_GET['s']` is not empty and inside the if function you are redirecting again to a URL that contain a `$_GET['s'] with an additional get parameter which is post_type.

Try to do it in the following way, just add another check to check if the post type isn't specified, its not the best solution but it would solve your problem.

```php
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) && empty($_GET['post_type')) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) . ( "&post_type=product" ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for taking the time to post the solution & also explain why I was getting the redirect issues.

Comment: Hi @Pixeljack, no worries I am glad that I was able to provide you with some help, can you accept the solution it by clicking the [check-mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.